# Error in sending fax

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use the following code for sending a FAX:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!IsPostBack)
{ FaxDocument(@"E:\ss.doc", "04428257363");
}
} public int FaxDocument(String TheFile, string faxnumber)
{
int JobID = 0; FAXCOMEXLib.FaxServer faxsrv = new FAXCOMEXLib.FaxServerClass();
try
{ faxsrv.Connect(Environment.MachineName); FaxDocumentClass faxdoc = new FAXCOMEXLib.FaxDocumentClass();
//*** How can I add 2 or more attachments to my fax Body with the use of one coverpage?
faxdoc.Body = @"E:\ss.doc"; //******************************************************************************************
faxdoc.Priority = FAX_PRIORITY_TYPE_ENUM.fptNORMAL; faxdoc.CoverPageType = FAXCOMEXLib.FAX_COVERPAGE_TYPE_ENUM.fcptLOCAL;
faxdoc.CoverPage = "TestCoverPage";
faxdoc.ScheduleType = FAXCOMEXLib.FAX_SCHEDULE_TYPE_ENUM.fstNOW;
faxdoc.DocumentName = "Fax Transmission"; faxdoc.Recipients.Add(faxnumber, "Lexicon");
faxdoc.AttachFaxToReceipt = false;
faxdoc.Note = "Here is the info you requested";
faxdoc.Subject = "Today's fax";
faxdoc.ConnectedSubmit(faxsrv);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Response.Write(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
faxsrv.Disconnect();
}
return JobID;
}
}

However, I get the following error:

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {CDA8ACB0-8CF5-4F6C-9BA2-5931D40C8CAE} failed due to the following error: 80040154.
```

Any help into solving this error is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is the error `Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {CDA8ACB0-8CF5-4F6C-9BA2-5931D40C8CAE} failed due to the following error: 80040154.`

Comment: Can not find the fax object/program on the server, or did not have permission to run it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in yours component registration... 
Have you registered the component with regsvr32? take a look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/88a6ea68-f476-4231-822f-27fabe59f458/) 
Or maybe the problem can be the 64-bit architecture, if the component is deployed to work with 32-bit. [This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfx64bit/thread/46476e78-33c5-41a0-b7ea-0bb0dcb39782/) can help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to some missing permissions on the account running the service. you can have a look [Here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1348572.aspx) for a possible solution to your problem

Answer (score 0):

This issue does not only pertains to 64 bit OS, it also pops up in Windows XP.
In Windows XP this process resolved my issue:
Go to Control Panel -> Add Remove Program Files -> Add remove Windows Components -> Check Fax Services Check box if it is unchecked, insert Windows XP CD and install fax services. Restart your system. That's it.